# how to disable typeahead:active when focusing a filled-in text field in a remote typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm using typeahead.js and it's great but here's my use case: I have a text field that is already filled in with a string on the server side when the page is loaded, so I don't want the suggestions menu to be shown when the user focuses the text field.

typeahead.js seems to *always* show the menu when focusing the text field. This makes sense since `minLength` is 2 and the text field value is something like "Tony" (or whatever). But I've tried using `hint: false` and calling `$('.typeahead').typeahead('close')` inside a callback for the `typeahead:active` event, and neither seem to stop the menu from being shown.

Here's the init code I'm using:

```
$('#locationInput').typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: false,
    minLength: 2
},
{
    name: 'locations',
    display: 'name',
    source: typeaheadLocations, // a simple Bloodhound instance
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(locationObj) {
            return $('<div>' + locationObj.name + '</div>');
        }
    }
});
```

There *is* a slight delay between when I focus the text field and the menu is actually shown, because the remote GET has to be run. So I'm guessing I would need to prevent that somehow, after it's focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like closing the menu in the `typeahead:open` event does the trick, but this seems pretty hack-ish to me. :(

```
$('#locationInput').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
},
{
    name: 'locations',
    display: 'name',
    source: typeaheadLocations,
    templates: {
        suggestion: function suggestion(locationObj) {
            return $('<div>' + locationObj.name + '</div>');
        }
    }

}).on('typeahead:open', function(e) {
    var $input = $(e.currentTarget);

    if (!$input.data('wasFocusedOnce')) {
        $input.data('wasFocusedOnce', true);
        $input.typeahead('close');
    }

}).on('typeahead:close', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).removeData('wasFocusedOnce');
}).on('keydown', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).data('wasFocusedOnce', true);
});
```

If anyone knows of a better way to do this, I'm all ears!

Comment: It's 2018, and this is still the only way I've found that works.

Comment: @TimScarborough It's actually 2019 :D

Comment: guys! you have no idea how happy I am to see this in 2020!!!!

Comment: And again in 2022!